# How do you match a string surrounded by optional whitespace with SBT Parsers

Tags: scala, parsing, sbt

I'm trying to parse a command line argument for an sbt InputTask using SBT Parsers (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Parsing-Input.html) but I'm failing to write a parser to match the following pseudo-regex:

```
\w+(-n|--dry-run)\w+
```

Here's the most sensible way of expressing this that I can think of. The results here should be `Some(true)` if the input string matches.

```
import sbt.complete.Parser
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

val dryRunOptions: Parser[String] = OptSpace ~> ("-n" | "--dry-run") <~ OptSpace
val dryRunParser: Parser[Boolean] = flag(dryRunOptions)

Parser(dryRunParser)("-n").result
Parser(dryRunParser)(" -n").result
Parser(dryRunParser)("-n ").result
Parser(dryRunParser)(" -n ").result

Parser(dryRunParser)("--dry-run").result
Parser(dryRunParser)(" --dry-run").result
Parser(dryRunParser)("--dry-run ").result
Parser(dryRunParser)(" --dry-run ").result
```

Unfortunately, this does not match any of these cases!

```
res0: Option[Boolean] = None
res1: Option[Boolean] = None
res2: Option[Boolean] = None
res3: Option[Boolean] = None

res4: Option[Boolean] = None
res5: Option[Boolean] = None
res6: Option[Boolean] = None
res7: Option[Boolean] = None
```

I can get this to match several of the cases with a couple of variations on this but never all of them. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking correctness of your parser in the wrong way. It looks like that in this case you should use `.resultEmpty.isValid` instead of `.result`, like in [tests here](https://github.com/sbt/util/blob/1.0/internal/util-complete/src/test/scala/ParserTest.scala#L150). Then it occurs that your code works fine:

```
import sbt.complete.Parser
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._

val dryRunOptions: Parser[String] = OptSpace ~> ("-n" | "--dry-run") <~ OptSpace
val dryRunParser: Parser[Boolean] = flag(dryRunOptions)

val test = Seq("-n", " -n", "-n ", " -n   ",
  "--dry-run", " --dry-run", "--dry-run ", " --dry-run   ")

test.foldLeft(true)((b:Boolean, input:String) =>
  b && Parser(dryRunParser)(input).resultEmpty.isValid)
```

And the result:

```
res0: Boolean = true
```